# How to use getEval in selenium C#.net?

Tags: javascript, selenium

can i use like this
selenium.getEval("var val= document.getElementById('name').value;")

Answer (score 0):

`documetn` should be `document`

also aren't you trying the following?

```
string result = selenium.GetEval("document.getElementById('name').value;");
```

Comment: selenium.GetEval("documet.documetElement.all.login.elements").it will work or not. login mean <form> tag name

Comment: string result = selenium.GetEval("window.document.getElementById('name').value;");